# values are getting disappeared after selecting the value and going to next dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i want to remove the values once user select it from dropdown so that the same value doesn't come on to the next dropdown, but the value which is select disappears on adding the next row or dropdown i mean the placeholder of dropdown goes missing. This is all what i have tried yet and you can find the codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-monad-1yexs?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="openModal()" class="cpasc-button">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" id="add-user-modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="display-flex;">
            <div class="header">
              <i
                class="ti-close closeIcon float-right"
                @click="closeModal()"
              ></i>
              <slot name="modal-header">Color Palette</slot>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="display-flex">
            <span style="margin-right:180px;padding:24px 24px 10px"
              >Fields</span
            >
            <span style="margin-right:110px;padding:24px 0px 10px"
              >Colors
            </span>
            <span style="padding:24px 24px 10px 0px">Action</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
            <div class="display-flex">
              <span style="width:240px;margin-right:10px">
                <select
                  class="form-control"
                  @click="mktChoice($event)"
                  v-model="input.fields"
                >
                  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
                  <option v-for="(kpi, i) in selval" :value="kpi" :key="i">{{
                    kpi
                  }}</option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-right:10px">
                <input
                  v-model="input.color"
                  type="color"
                  name="option_color"
                  value="#DCEBD8"
                  @change="custom($event)"
                  list="colors"
                  style="height:35px;width:155px"
                />
                <datalist id="colors">
                  <option
                    v-for="(color, i) in colors"
                    :value="color"
                    :key="i"
                    @change="setColor(color)"
                    >{{ color }}</option
                  >
                </datalist>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-right:10px;">
                <i
                  style="width:100px;height:105px"
                  @click="deleteRow(index)"
                  class="ti-trash btn-outline-danger"
                />
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              @click="addRow"
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              style="margin-right:10px"
            >
              Add Row
            </button>
            <button @click="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      kpiValues: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
      mktchoice: "",
      selval: [],
      inputs: [],
      selectedColor: "",
      colors: [
        "#e20000",
        "#377eb8",
        "#4daf4a",
        "#250056 ",
        "#ff9300",
        "#df216d",
        "#a65628",
        "#0768fd",
        "#00c221",
        "#9e54b0",
        "#ffff33",
        "#10558a",
        "#595959",
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.addRow();
    this.selval = this.kpiValues;
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({ fields: this.selval[0], color: "#DCEBD8" });
      this.selval = this.selval.filter(
        (item) => !this.mktchoice.includes(item)
      );
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    },
    mktChoice(event) {
      this.mktchoice = event.target.value;
    },
    custom(event) {
      this.selectedColor = event.target.value;
    },
    openModal() {
      document.getElementById("add-user-modal").style.display = "block";
    },
    closeModal() {
      document.getElementById("add-user-modal").style.display = "none";
      this.$emit("cancel");
    },
    setColor(color) {
      this.selectedColor = color;
    },
    submit() {
      console.log(this.inputs);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.closeIcon {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.header {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  height: 20px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 24px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}
.modal-content {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off, you can disable each selectable value based off if the inputs contain the selected value with a computed object

```
<option value="" selected default>Choose</option>
<option v-for="(kpi, i) in kpiValues" :value="kpi" :key="i" :disabled="selectedKpis.includes(kpi)">{{kpi}}</option>
```

```
computed: {
      selectedKpis() {
          return this.kpiValues.filter(value => {
            return this.inputs.map(input => input.fields).includes(value);
          })
      }
  },
```

Secondly, Dont push a default value when creating a row.

```
addRow() {
    this.inputs.push({ fields: '', color: "#DCEBD8" });
},
```

All code amended below.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button @click="openModal()" class="cpasc-button">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" id="add-user-modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="display-flex;">
            <div class="header">
              <i
                class="ti-close closeIcon float-right"
                @click="closeModal()"
              ></i>
              <slot name="modal-header">Color Palette</slot>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="display-flex">
            <span style="margin-right:180px;padding:24px 24px 10px"
              >Fields</span
            >
            <span style="margin-right:110px;padding:24px 0px 10px"
              >Colors
            </span>
            <span style="padding:24px 24px 10px 0px">Action</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
            <div class="display-flex">
              <span style="width:240px;margin-right:10px">
                <select
                  class="form-control"
                  @click="mktChoice($event)"
                  v-model="input.fields"
                >
                  <option value="" selected default>Choose</option>
                  <option v-for="(kpi, i) in kpiValues" :value="kpi" :key="i" :disabled="selectedKpis.includes(kpi)">{{kpi}}</option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-right:10px">
                <input
                  v-model="input.color"
                  type="color"
                  name="option_color"
                  value="#DCEBD8"
                  @change="custom($event)"
                  list="colors"
                  style="height:35px;width:155px"
                />
                <datalist id="colors">
                  <option
                    v-for="(color, i) in colors"
                    :value="color"
                    :key="i"
                    @change="setColor(color)"
                    >{{ color }}</option
                  >
                </datalist>
              </span>
              <span style="margin-right:10px;">
                <i
                  style="width:100px;height:105px"
                  @click="deleteRow(index)"
                  class="ti-trash btn-outline-danger"
                />
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              @click="addRow"
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              style="margin-right:10px"
            >
              Add Row
            </button>
            <button @click="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      kpiValues: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
      mktchoice: "",
      inputs: [],
      selectedColor: "",
      colors: [
        "#e20000",
        "#377eb8",
        "#4daf4a",
        "#250056 ",
        "#ff9300",
        "#df216d",
        "#a65628",
        "#0768fd",
        "#00c221",
        "#9e54b0",
        "#ffff33",
        "#10558a",
        "#595959",
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.addRow();
  },
  computed: {
      selectedKpis() {
          return this.kpiValues.filter(value => {
            return this.inputs.map(input => input.fields).includes(value);
          })
      }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.inputs.push({ fields: '', color: "#DCEBD8" });
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    },
    mktChoice(event) {
      this.mktchoice = event.target.value;
    },
    custom(event) {
      this.selectedColor = event.target.value;
    },
    openModal() {
      document.getElementById("add-user-modal").style.display = "block";
    },
    closeModal() {
      document.getElementById("add-user-modal").style.display = "none";
      this.$emit("cancel");
    },
    setColor(color) {
      this.selectedColor = color;
    },
    submit() {
      console.log(this.inputs);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.closeIcon {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.header {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  height: 20px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 24px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.3rem - 1px);
}
.modal-content {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
</style>
```